# CuO (monoclinic) crystallographic plane and their relaxed surface energy

Tags: reference-request, crystal-structure, crystallography

I want to calculate wulff construction for CuO of space group C2/c. Can any one help me with its crystallographic plane/Miller indices and their corresponding relaxed surface energy? If you can provide any related paper that will be very helpful..

Note that, I know the Miller indices of CuO, but doesn't know their corresponding surface energy.

Comment: I would imagine that if you already know your surface facets, you could  calculate these surface energies using your tool of choice - quantum or classical force field-based methods. A starting point know how to do this could be David Sholl's textbook `Density functional theory: a practical introduction`.

Comment: I was hoping to have a paper that I can cite directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend that you calculate directly.  You can use a package like ASE to generate terminations of a given surface using the [build](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/surface.html#ase.build.surface) module.  For the treatment of surface energies I would refer you to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9610046.pdf).  If you find that an automated approach to surface terminations would be useful you may also want to look at [CatKit](https://catkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Once you have surface energies, wulff constructions can be done using [WulffPack](https://gitlab.com/materials-modeling/wulffpack).

As for a source for CuO surface energies, I did not find a good source in my quick search but you can probably find a couple sources for different facets.  I don't recommend you go this route though as you will have to piece together different results from different papers.  Though, to some degree this is good.  This means it will be a useful result in of itself.

Comment: +1. Considering how fast we got an answer, this question has potential to appear on HNQ if the question and answer get enough upvotes.

Comment: @Tristan Maxson I'm not good in crystallography. Can you plz share some resource for surface termination and how to use them? +1 for your answer.

Comment: All I have is the cif file of that structure and its corresponding xrd peak miller indices.

Comment: Do you have any experience with computational modelling?  If not, then you may need to find paper resources or find someone who can do this work for you.  Learning shouldn't be too difficult either but it helps massively to have someone to show you initially.

Comment: @TristanMaxson I do have some working experience in quantum espresso software and dft calculation but at a beginner level.

Comment: @TristanMaxson I don't have someone who could help or guide me. If you can help me with this surface energy calculation that would be nice. However, I found a paper on the surface energy of C2/c spacegroup CuO  https://knepublishing.com/index.php/KnE-Engineering/article/view/504

Comment: If that paper is sufficient for what you need then, you might answer your own question.  If you have surface energies though, you don't need to do calculations you can just use the wulffpack software with the data you have.  Just be cautious if you only have one source of information.

Comment: Still I'm curious about the process you tell here. If you can share some resource I can try to learn them.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Still I'm curious about the process you tell here. If you can share some resource I can try to learn them

Comment: If you have some beginner experience with espresso, I recommend you simply generate some surfaces with ASE or VESTA and see if you can follow any literature on surface energies.  In your other question, I linked two generic DFT resources that will guide you step by step in these sorts of calculations.